# Getting 401 error for any exception in spring boot java application

Tags: java, security

**HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(request);
chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);**

where chain is coming from the FilterChain in function call

In this response errorStatus is 200 but when it is processed till front end errorStatus is becoming 401 every time even though I am throwing custom exception

Comment: I think you need to flesh out the description. With the given information I cannot follow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.